# PHP not going to last if

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem, i'm really new to PHP. If i have some value in skype, tag, senha i need to update, not insert, how can i do that? I already have id from user to update. Edit: If i don't have i need to insert, if i have i need to update, sorry.

```
<?php

                    if(isset($_POST['cadastrar']) && $_POST['cadastrar'] == "register"){
                        $skype = $_POST['skype'];
                        $tag = $_POST['tag'];
                        $senha = $_POST['senha'];

                            if(EMPTY($skype)|| EMPTY($tag) || EMPTY($senha)){
                                 echo '<script>
                                    alert("Insira todas as informações.");
                                    window.location.href = "http://pdb.servegame.com/a/acesso/ui/tags";                                 
                                </script>';
                                exit;
                                };


                             $cadastrar = "INSERT INTO tag (logintag, tag, skype, senha, idtag) VALUES ('$login', '$tag', '$skype', '$senha', '$id');";
                            if(mysql_query($cadastrar)){
                                 echo '<script>
                                            alert("Ok! TAG Atualizada.");
                                            window.location.href = "http://pdb.servegame.com/a/acesso/ui/tags";                                 
                                        </script>';
                            }else{
                                echo 'Erro ao cadastrar, por favor entre em contato conosco';
                            }
                    }



    ?>
```

Comment: you can lookup "on duplicate key update"
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$list= "SELECT idtag FROM tag where idtag = " . $id;
mysql_query($list);
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
    $cadastrar =
    "UPDATE tag SET logintag = \" $login \", tag = \" $tag \"," . 
    "skype = \" $skype \", senha = \" $senha \" , idtag = \" $id \" " . 
    "WHERE idtag = ".$id;
} else {
$cadastrar= 
    "INSERT INTO tag ".
    "(logintag, tag, skype, senha, idtag) ".
    "VALUES ".
    "('$login','$tag','$skype','$senha','$id');";
}
```

Comment: Barney, now its showing the last updated register in mysql to everyone. It update, but show to everyone the last updated register.

Comment: Actually I am not getting what you are trying to say!

Comment: Sorry, i just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
replace 
$cadastrar = "INSERT INTO tag (logintag, tag, skype, senha, idtag) VALUES ('$login', '$tag', '$skype', '$senha', '$id');";
with
 $cadastrar= 
"INSERT INTO tag ".
"(logintag, tag, skype, senha, idtag) ".
"VALUES ".
"('$login','$tag','$skype','$senha','$id');";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code

```
$cadExist = "SELECT idtag FROM tag where idtag = " . $id;
if($cadExist){
    $cadastrar =
    "UPDATE tag SET logintag = \" $login \", tag = \" $tag \"," . 
    "skype = \" $skype \", senha = \" $senha \" , idtag = \" $id \" " . 
    "WHERE idtag = ".$id;
} else {
$cadastrar= 
    "INSERT INTO tag ".
    "(logintag, tag, skype, senha, idtag) ".
    "VALUES ".
    "('$login','$tag','$skype','$senha','$id');";
}
```

You can replace **idtag** for every property you want to filter, even the filter in the **WHERE** 
here:

```
SELECT idtag FROM tag where idtag = " . $id
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$cadastrar = "INSERT INTO tag (logintag, tag, skype, senha, idtag) VALUES ('$login', '$tag', '$skype', '$senha', '$id');";
```

with:

```
$cadastrar = "update tag set logintag='$login', tag='$tag', skype='$skype', senha='$senha' where idtag='$id';";
```